# Why is xslt adding attributes itself in <copy>?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xhtml-1.0-strict

I use xslt 1.0 to do some manipulations on xhtml file. But I wanted to start from an identical copy. To my surprise **xsl adds attributes that were absent in the original file**. Please explain this phenomenon. I would rather avoid it to make it easier to compare source and result files.

I tried both xsltproc and msxsl. No difference. I get `rowspan` and `colspan` added to all `td` elements.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
<title>Anything</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td class="skl" >test</td><td class="kwota" >1 800,00</td></tr>
</table>
</body>                    

</html>
```

xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  >
  <xsl:output method="xml"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    encoding="windows-1250"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
  />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="node()|@*|processing-instruction()|comment()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the only difference is this line:

```
<tr><td class="skl" rowspan="1" colspan="1">test</td><td class="kwota" rowspan="1" colspan="1">1 800,00</td></tr>
```

Validation of source file against the dtd shows no errors. I can insert these attributes into the source file to workaround the problem, but I'm curious about the cause of this mess.

**Edit:**
I use original dtd downloaded (with a 20 seconds delay) from
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd

```
<!ATTLIST td
  %attrs;
  abbr        %Text;         #IMPLIED
  axis        CDATA          #IMPLIED
  headers     IDREFS         #IMPLIED
  scope       %Scope;        #IMPLIED
  rowspan     %Number;       "1"
  colspan     %Number;       "1"
  %cellhalign;
  %cellvalign;
  >
```

Comment: Check that you don't have a local copy of the XHTML DTD or that you are using a catalog to point to a wrong version. If your DTD is declared FIXED attributes, XSLT is **NOT** adding them. They were always there in the model data, even if not seen lexically.

Comment: Refer to [XHTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict) . See section on ATTLIST for element `td`. The defaultdecl is "default to 1". Although it is not FIXED. The behaviour you are observing is what happens when it is the defaultdecl is annotated with `FIXED`.

Comment: Ah ... explaining in answer box soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XSLT processors are behaving perfectly correctly. No new attributes are being added. The rowspan attributes were always in your input file via the DTD reference. Whether the value of "1" for a rowspan is serialized as an explicit attribute or implied by your doctype declaration makes no difference to the model data.

The ATTLIST above shows that the rowspan and the colspan have a default value of 1. There is no way **not** to have these attributes and still conform to XHTML 1.1 strict. The other attributes annotated as #IMPLIED means they are optional.

I hope that explains it.

Comment: Sean, that explains the thing completely. Let me rephrase it now that I know the reason: **It's not the xslt processor that adds the attributes. They are added by DTD.**

Comment: This behaviour can be extremely annoying, although it is correct. Saxon has an option to prevent it (which works so long as the XML parser is cooperative). Another approach is to detach the DTD for the purpose of the transformation, e.g. by using catalogs.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of disabling the "feature" in the processors I was able to test.

### libxml

**xsltproc**:  `--nodtdattr`

**libxslt / libxml**: don't specify `XML_PARSE_DTDATTR` when loading the source, for example in [xmlReadFile](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadFile)

### msxml

**msxsl**:  `-xe` - don't resolve externals

**Msxml.DomDocument**: `doc.resolveExternals = False` and `doc.validateOnParse = False` before `load`, also disables whole dtd

[resolveExternals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> In MSXML 3.0 and MSXML 6.0 the default resolveExternals value is True. In MSXML 6.0, the default setting is False.

Yeah, that's stupid. But I only copied it from MS. Should be *3.0 and 4.0 True, 6.0 False* I guess.

[PopulateElementDefaultValues Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) introduced in 6.0 SP1 has an attractive description, but it doesn't work for me with dtds.